# How to change label text with click event

Tags: c#, asp.net, mouseclick-event

I have a label in called "lblnotify" in site.Master(asp.net).

```
 *<div class = "notification">
         <asp:Label ID="lblnotify" runat="server" text ="0 "></asp:Label> 
          </div>*
```

And in the code behind file, i have a method that is supposed to replace the text of "lblnotify" with another.

```
*public void notificationManager()
    {

       try
       {
            string i = lblnotify.Text;
            i = i + "new";
            lblnotify.Text = i ;

            Label1.Text = (i);

       }
       catch (Exception er)
        {
            Response.Write("Exception Occured:   " + er);
        }
    }*
```

notificationManager is triggered in a submit button in another class

```
*protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {         
            appSite call = new appSite();              
            call.notificationManager();

    }*
```

but this gives me the error **Object reference not set to an instance of an object** at

```
 *string i = lblnotify.Text;*
```

in the try block when i comment  try-catch and the same error  at

```
 *Response.Write("Exception Occured:   " + er);*
```

in the catch block when i do not comment try-catch. have tried all i can but still get the error. Your help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: what is this kine for  Label1.Text = (i.ToString());

Comment: i is string .. why ToString ?

Comment: Thanks for the response, just edited that out

Comment: is lblNotify in the same page with your notificationManager() ?

Comment: @ matzone, the lblNotify is in the asp.net page while the notificationManager() is in the c# page of the asp.net page - the code behind page

Comment: does notificationManager() is on the same page of btnSubmit_Click?

Comment: @JRC notificationManager() , btnSubmit_Click and <div class = "notification"> are all on different pages

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what are you going to do!, but controls are initialized in init page life cycle ,
and only thing you can do is to init your label control in constructor of you page class :

```
public appSite()
{
  lblnotify = new Label();
}
```

Comment: Thanxs for your reply. When a use the new key word, i do not get any error but the text for lblnotify does not change

Comment: its clear, if you want to send a value to another page you should use queryString or SessionState and set the text box value in page load event, I think you should read some more about web tech specially asp.net :)